# Create a list/array from custom types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to make a list or array from all possible variants of a custom type.

Ex.
The custom type:

```
export type FruitType= 'Apple' | 'Orange' | 'Strawberry' | 'Banana';
```

Wanted result:

```
const FruitArray = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Strawberry', 'Banana']
```

Is this achievable or is hardcoding the list the only way?

I'm working in React with typescript

Answer (score 4):

As TypeScript is just transpiled to JavaScript, the type information is only available at compile time, not at run time. You will have to re-define the value somewhere they're available at run time.

What you can do is define the array and then define a type based on it:

```
const fruitArray = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Strawberry', 'Banana'] as const;
type FruitType = typeof fruitArray[number];
const fruit: FruitType = 'Apple';
```

However, `FruitType` will only allow values that are actually hard-coded into `fruitArray` from the very beginning.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `enum` instead `type` then you can write the next code:

```
enum FruitType {
  Apple = 'Apple',
  Orange = 'Orange',
  Strawberry = 'Strawberry',
  Banana = 'Banana',
}

const array = Object.values(FruitType);
```